# How to convert List<T> to HashSet<T> in C#?

Tags: c#, list, hashset

I have a List that has duplicates of objects. To solve that, I need to convert the List into a HashSet (in C#). Does anyone know how?

Comment: This is a List, not an array, though.

Comment: For this kind of question they are both `IList<YourType>`.

Comment: The answer addresses the problem—"HashSet has a constructor that takes an IEnumerable".

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Make sure your object's class overrides `Equals` and `GetHashCode` and then you can pass the `List<T>` to `HashSet<T>` [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<YourType>(yourList);
```

You may see: [What is the best algorithm for an overridden System.Object.GetHashCode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode)

Comment: I recommend the Distinct() function;  IE: somelist.Distinct();

Answer (score 12):

An alternative way would be

```
var yourlist = new List<SomeClass>();

// [...]

var uniqueObjs = yourlist.Distinct();  //Gives you a List with unique Objects of the List.
```

Note that this is only possible, if `SomeClass` overrides `GetHashCode` and `Equals` in some way. This is also true for

```
var uniqueObjs = new HashSet<SomeType>(yourOriginalList);
```

Otherwise you could implement you own `IEqualityComnparer`-class and pass it to distinct.

Note that with the `Distinct()` approach, you can also look for distinct property values of the object in the list:

```
var uniqueNames = yourlist.Select(obj => obj.Name).Distinct();
```

and some more...

Comment: I much prefer this answer to the ones that answer the specific question. "I want a house with 2 doors, so I'm going to bulldoze this house with 1 door and build a new house from scratch"

Comment: you would need to implement IEquatable on 'SomeClass' for that to work

Comment: @YTAM as far as i am concerned, this is also the case if you want to create a new Hashset based on the original list.

Comment: And the mere fact that they're considered duplicate means they must be mathematically/logically equatable in some way.

Answer (score 9):

If your type implements `IEquatable<T>`, `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` correctly, then you don't need to do the de-duplication yourself. You can use Linq's `Distinct()` to do so like this:

```
myList = myList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Most of the time I need a set to remove duplicates from a list. This is a great way to achieve that.